# Get attribute of span in Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need get the attributes of a `<span></span>`. I have problems with this. I dont know how achieve this. 
I want get the attribute "validacion" ("value1 value2 value3")

```
<span data-id="345" ng-click="getAtributte($event.target)" validacion="value1 value2 value3">Button</span>

$scope.getAtributte = function (item) {
    console.log(angular.element(item)); 
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can use it in two different ways :**

- angular.element(item)[0].attributes.validacion.nodeValue
- angular.element(item).attr('validacion')

**DEMO**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl',function($scope) {
    $scope.getAtributte = function (item) {
    console.log(angular.element(item)[0].attributes.validacion.nodeValue); 
    console.log(angular.element(item).attr('validacion')); 
};
});

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
 <span data-id="345" ng-click="getAtributte($event.target)" validacion="value1 value2 value3">Button</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.getAtributte = function (item) {
    console.log(angular.element(item).attr('validacion')); 
};
```

The fact that you are trying to do this suggests that there is probably a better (more angular) approach to this.